# How can i install a java ME embedded application on the actual device?

Tags: java, deployment, java-me, embedded

Like the title says, i would like to know how to deploy a java ME embedded application on a real device, but i can't find any information on this subject. The application is supposed to be install on a washing machine board.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Oracle website that discusses deployment options:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/training/emulator/index.html

Look specifically at the section titled "RUN YOUR APPLICATION ON A REAL PHONE".

Essentially, the java ME application is made of two parts: One is the jar file of the application itself and the other is a plain text file known as the application descriptor file. You host both files on a webserver and link to the url for the application descriptor. Thus on a real device you just browse to the url for the application descriptor and select it and that should start the installation process on the device.

Comment: There may well be things to learn from that, but you seem to be assuming that the washing machine has an outgoing net connection.  It may... but it may also just be a washing machine with a fancy UI, rather than a smartphone trapped in the body of a washing machine.